# Schengen Visa Single or multiple entry

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I want to travel from Cochin to Birmingham  and  later from Birmingham to Italy to Austria to Ireland and back to Birmingham in 10 days. I will be back to Cochin within a month. I have already received UK Visa.

I am applying for Schengen visa from India as per my itinerary as mentioned above. Should I need a single entry visa ?

Comment: Hmmm...  This seems like a no brainer, was there something in particular making you think otherwise?

Comment: @aGayotFow some recent questions leave me with the impression that some people worry that entering a second Schengen country directly from the first Schengen country constitutes a second entry into the Schengen area.  This is obviously quite contrary to the underlying principles of the Schengen agreement, but it may not be so obvious to those who are less familiar with such matters.

Comment: All the answers are very clear and useful for new travellers to schengen countries

Answer (score 1):

A single-entry visa will suffice, if I understand your itinerary correctly.  You will enter the Schengen area once, when you travel from Birmingham to Italy.  You will then travel from Italy to Austria, remaining in the Schengen area.  You will then travel to Ireland, leaving the Schengen area.

Because the remainder of your trip is entirely outside the Schengen area, the single-entry visa is enough.

Comment: @DJClayworth a stop in the UK would only be a problem if the OP's UK visa is restricted to a limited number of entries.

Comment: @DJClayworth no.  Ireland is not part of the Schengen area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you only need a single-entry Schengen visa to enter Italy from Birmingham. Travel between Italy and Austria is considered intra Schengen and does not require a Schengen visa.